# RethinkDB - How to return a sliding window on grouped data

Tags: rethinkdb

I have some objects:

```
[
  { 'time': 1, 'data': { '1': 10, '2': 100} },
  { 'time': 2, 'data': { '1': 20, '2': 100} },
  { 'time': 3, 'data': { '1': 30, '2': 200} },
  { 'time': 4, 'data': { '1': 40, '2': 100} },
  { 'time': 5, 'data': { '1': 50, '2': 300} },
  { 'time': 6, 'data': { '1': 60, '2': 200} }
]
```

and two variables `width` and `overlap`:

- `width` - max length of `'values'` list
- `overlap` - number of mutual values

Assume `width = 3` and `overlap = 2`. Is there any way to obtain following?

```
[ { 'key': '1',
    'rows': [ { 'time': 1, 'values': [10,20,30] },
              { 'time': 2, 'values': [20,30,40] },
              { 'time': 3, 'values': [30,40,50] },
              { 'time': 4, 'values': [40,50,60] }
            ]
  },
  { 'key': '2',
    'rows': [ { 'time': 1, 'values': [100,100,200] },
              { 'time': 2, 'values': [100,200,100] },
              { 'time': 3, 'values': [200,100,300] },
              { 'time': 4, 'values': [100,300,200] }
            ]
  } ]
```

So far I've managed to get this:

```
[ { 'key': '1',
    'row': { 'time': 1, 'values': [10,20,30,40,50,60] }
  },
  { 'key': '2',
    'row': { 'time': 1, 'values': [100,100,200,100,300,200] }
  } ]
```

using this:

```
.concatMap(function(item) {
  return item('data').keys().map(function(key) {
    return {
      'key': key,
      'row': { 
        'time': item('time'),
        'values': [item('data')(key)]
      }
    }
  })
})
.group('key')
.ungroup()
.map(function(list) { 
  return list('reduction').reduce(function(left, right) {
    return {
      'key': left('key'),
      'row': {
        'time': left('row')('time'),
        'values': left('row')('values').union(right('row')('values'))
      }
    }
  })
})
```

Maybe I need to add something or to change everything?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is pretty similar to mlucy's solution, but it doesn't assume that the `time` fields are consecutive integers.  The data is sorted by `time` before the `concatMap` below - for large datasets, this should be done with an index.

```
r.expr(data)
 .orderBy('time')
 .concatMap(function (row) {
   return row('data').coerceTo('array').map(function (pair) {
     return { key: pair(0), value: pair(1), time: row('time') };
   });
 })
 .group('key')
 .ungroup()
 .map(function (g) {
   let rows = g('reduction').count().do(function (c) {
     return r.range(c.sub(2)).map(function (i) {
       let values = r.range(3).map(function (j) {
         return g('reduction')(i.add(j))('value');
       }).coerceTo('array');
       return { 'time': g('reduction')(i)('time'), 'values': values };
     }).coerceTo('array');
   });
   return { key: g('group'), rows: rows };
 })
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want something like this:

```
r.table('test').orderBy('time').concatMap(function(row) {
  return row('data').coerceTo('array');
}).group(function(pair) {
  return pair(0);
}).map(function(pair) {
  return pair(1);
}).ungroup().map(function(group) {
  return {
    key: group('group'),
    rows: group('reduction').do(function(x) {
      return r.range(x.count().sub(2)).map(function(i) {
        return {
          time: i,
          values: r.range(3).map(function(o) {
            return x(i.add(o));
          }).coerceTo('array')
        };
      }).coerceTo('array');
    })
  };
})
```

(Where the `.sub(2)` and `.range(3)` need to change based on the width and overlap.)